# how to query array of nested json in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

i was **scraping** large and complex data and have problem in a column that has array of nested json. to simulate the issue: -

```
CREATE TABLE public.test
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('test_id_seq'::regclass),
  testval jsonb
)
```

sample data

```
INSERT INTO test (id, test) 
VALUES 
(111,
'[{"type": {"value": 0, "displayName": "test0"}, "value": "outertestvalue0"}, {"type": {"value": 1, "displayName": "test1"}, "value": "outertestvalue1"}]'
);
INSERT INTO test (id, test) 
VALUES 
(222,
'[{"type": {"value": 2, "displayName": "test2"}, "value": "outertestvalue2"}, {"type": {"value": 3, "displayName": "test3"}, "value": "outertestvalue3"}]'
);
```

question is how to filter out base on specific conditions

```
select * from test where testval->'type' ->>'displayName'='test1';
```

this didnt work. can anyone point me to right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the JSON containment operator:

```
WHERE testval @> '[ { "type": { "displayName": "test1" } } ]'
```

This can be supported with a GIN index on the column.

Comment: thanks. is the key 'type' be able to be done in wildcard?

Comment: No. If the data were in a normal relational structure, it wouldn't be a problem...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a wildcard search (e.g. LIKE) you need to unnest the array:

```
select t.*
from test t
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_array_elements(t.testval) as a(x)
              where a.x -> 'type' ->> 'displayName' like 'foo%');
```

With Postgres 12 this can be written a bit simpler using the new `jsonb_path_exists()` function:

```
select *
from test
where jsonb_path_exists(testval, '$.type.displayName ? (@ starts with "foo")');
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=295c5a40dbcbc8d76497faa27b3c35c0)